# How to add a single backslash character to a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to insert backslash before apostrophe in "children's world" string. Is there a easy way to do it?

```
irb(main):035:0> s = "children's world"
=> "children's world"
irb(main):036:0> s.gsub('\'', '\\\'')
=> "childrens worlds world"
```

Answer (score 15):

### Answer

You need some extra backslashes:

```rb
>> puts "children's world".gsub("'", '\\\\\'')
children\'s world
```

or slightly more concisely (since you don't need to escape the `'` in a double-quoted string):

```rb
>> puts "children's world".gsub("'", "\\\\'")
children\'s world
```

or even more concisely:

```rb
>> puts "children's world".gsub("'") { "\\'" }
children\'s world
```

### Explanation

Your `'\\\''` generates `\'` as a string:

```rb
>> puts '\\\''
\'
```

**and `\'` is a special replacement pattern in Ruby**. From [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods):

> you may refer to some special match variables using these combinations ... `\'` corresponds to `$'`, which contains string after match

So the `\'` that `gsub` sees in the second argument is being interpreted as a special pattern (everything in the original string after the match) instead of as a literal `\'`.

So what you want `gsub` to see is actually `\\'`, which can be produced by `'\\\\\''` or `"\\\\'"`.

Or, if you use the block form of `gsub` (`gsub("xxx") { "yyy" }`) then Ruby takes the replacement string `"yyy"` literally without trying to apply replacement patterns.

Note: If you have to create a replacement string with a lot of `\`s you could  take advantage of the fact that when you use `/.../` (or `%r{...}`) you don't have to double-escape the backslashes:

```rb
>> puts "children's world".gsub("'", /\\'/.source)
children\'s world
```

Or you could use a single-quoted heredoc: (using `<<'STR'` instead of just `<<STR`)

```rb
>> puts "children's world".gsub("'", <<'STR'.strip)
  \\'
STR
children\'s world
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>> puts s.gsub("'", "\\\\'")
children\'s world
```

Comment: @Jirapong the reason you're thinking it gets \\ is because the rails console doesn't display the string, but displays how one would construct the string. So if you enter "\\", it's going to display "\\" event though it's a string with a single backslash in it. To discover what's truly in the string, you should use **puts**. For example, puts "\\" will display a single backslash.

Comment: this was the right answer for me. I was going mad thinking ruby wouldn't allow me to do a single backslash - until I did:

`"\\".length #=> 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the string "\'" is meaningful to gsub in a replacement string. In order to make it work the way you want, you have to use the block form.

```
s.gsub("'") {"\\'"}
```