# adding backslash to fix character encoding in ruby string

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, web-scraping, utf-16

I'm sure this is very easy but I'm getting tied in a knot with all these backslashes.

I have some data that I'm scraping (politely) from a website. Occasionally a sentence comes to me looking something like this:

```
u00a362 000? you must be joking
```

Which should of course be '£2 000? you must be joking'. A short test in irb deciphered it.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > string = "u00a3"
  => "u00a3" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > string = "\u00a3"
  => "£"
```

Of course: add a backslash and it will be decoded. I created the following with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716767/how-to-add-a-single-backslash-character-to-a-string-in-ruby):

```
puts str.gsub('u00', '\\u00')
```

which resulted in `\u00a3` being output. This is all well and good, but I want it to be £ in the string itself. just `puts`ing it isn't enough.

It's no good doing `gsub('u00a3', '£')` as there will doubtless be other characters I'm missing.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning, the following is not really pretty.

```
str = "u00a362 000? you must be joking"
split_unicode = str.gsub(/(u00[a-z0-9]{2})/, "split_here\\1split_here").split(/split_here/)
final = split_unicode.map do |elem|
  if elem =~ /^u00/
    [("0x" + elem.gsub(/u00/, '')).hex].pack("U*")
  else
    elem
  end
end
puts final.join
```

So the idea here is to find `u00xx` values and convert them to hex. From there, we can use the [`pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206) method to output the right unicode characters.

It can also be crunched in an horrible one-liner!

```
puts (str.gsub(/(u00[a-z0-9]{2})/, "split_here\\1split_here").split(/split_here/).map {|elem| elem =~ /^u00/ ? [("0x" + elem.gsub(/u00/, '')).hex].pack("U*") : elem}).join
```

There might be a better solution (I hope!) but this one works.

Comment: hey, thanks very much for this. my first brush with 'pack'. I don't recognise what you're doing with the square brackets inside your map? When I run it in irb, I get the following: `Â£62 000? you must be joking` - where's that stray one come from?

Comment: `Array#pack("U*")` is usually coupled with `String#unpack("U*")`, which takes every character of a string and puts its unicode bit value in an array. So even if we have one value, we have to provide pack with an array. As for the `Â` coming out of no where, I have no idea. It works fine for me...

Comment: OK - I think `Â` is a different problem - turns out it's appearing  whenever i put a `£` anywhere, so it's coming from somewhere else. This solves my problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Iconv library for converting the incoming string. You might also take a look at the stringex gem.  It has methods to "go the other way" but it may provide the mappings you're looking for. That said if you've got bad encoding it can be impossible to get it right.