# Symbols through SSH

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am trying to open an SSH connection from a local machine to a remote machine by running `sender.rb` on the local machine, and call a script `receiver.rb` on the remote machine, providing a password as argument.

#### sender.rb

```
require 'net/ssh'

ssh_opts = {
    :host_name=>"19.09.20.18",
    :user=>"manual-ace",
    :password=>"42bike24",
    :port=>1800,
    :auth_methods=>["password"],
}

Net::SSH.start(nil, nil, ssh_opts) do |ssh|
  psw = "TEst$1234".encode("UTF-8")
  p ssh.exec!("ruby path/to/receiver.rb #{psw}")
end
```

#### receiver.rb

```
ARGV.each do |my_str|
  p my_str # OUTPUT: "TEst234"
end
```

I have a problem seemingly related to bash interpreting the string as a command. Symbols in the password are not received as they are sent. `$1` is removed from the text. Inserting `$` removes the following character; having two or more `$` removes all characters between the first one and the character following the last one (`T$Es$t12$34` becomes `T4`). Some other characters such as `<>\;"` have the same behaviour or raise `bash: (command): command not found`.

I tried working with [encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835846) and [`Shellwords`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476389). I'd like to to use [special characters for passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters) such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``, although [any printable character that the user inputs should be allowed](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72568).

Comment: So `['ruby', 'path/to/receiver.rb', psw].shelljoin` didn't work either?

Comment: BTW, this is certainly not an encoding problem – `$` has the same value in both, UTF-8 and ASCII.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, title and tags fixed

Comment: @Stefan `['ruby', 'path/to/receiver.rb', psw].shelljoin` works. If you want to post it as an answer I can accept the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to properly *escape* the arguments, e.g. via [`shelljoin`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shelljoin):

```
require 'shellwords'

psw = "TEst$1234"
['ruby', 'path/to/receiver.rb', psw].shelljoin
#=> "ruby path/to/receiver.rb TEst\\$1234"
```