# Strange Ruby behavior when replacing with \'X string

Tags: ruby, string-substitution

I am generating some RTF strings and need the \'bd code. I am having problem with the sub and gsub commands.

```
puts 'abc'.sub('a',"\\'B")  => "bcBbc"
```

The statement replaces the target with 'B' without the \', and copies the remainder of the string to the front. I've tried a lot of variations and it seems that the problem is the \' itself.

I have ways of getting around this, but I'd like to know whether I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or whether this is a quirk with Ruby.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716767/how-to-add-a-single-backslash-character-to-a-string-in-ruby/717057 may also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-sub):

> Similarly, `\&`, `\'`, `` \` ``, and `\+` correspond to special variables, `$&`, `$'`, `` $` ``, and `$+`, respectively.

And [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables), the documentation goes on to say:

> - `$~` is equivalent to [::last_match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match);
> - `$&` contains the complete matched text;
> - `` $` `` contains string before match;
> - `$'` contains string after match;
> - `$1`, `$2` and so on contain text matching first, second, etc capture group;
> - `$+` contains last capture group.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> m = /s(\w{2}).*(c)/.match('haystack') #=> #<MatchData "stac" 1:"ta" 2:"c">
> $~                                    #=> #<MatchData "stac" 1:"ta" 2:"c">
> Regexp.last_match                     #=> #<MatchData "stac" 1:"ta" 2:"c">
>
> $&      #=> "stac"
>         # same as m[0]
> $`      #=> "hay"
>         # same as m.pre_match
> $'      #=> "k"
>         # same as m.post_match
> $1      #=> "ta"
>         # same as m[1]
> $2      #=> "c"
>         # same as m[2]
> $3      #=> nil
>         # no third group in pattern
> $+      #=> "c"
>         # same as m[-1]
> ```

So, `\'` in a substitution replacement string has a special meaning. It means "The portion of the original string after the match" - which, in this case, is `"bc"`.

So rather than getting `\'Bbc`, you get `bcBbc`

Therefore unfortunately, in this odd scenario, you'd need to **double**-escape the backslashes:

```
puts 'abc'.sub('a',"\\\\'B")  => "\'Bbc"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting @3limin4t0r, I couldn't work out how to properly format code containing a backtick!

Comment: Thank you, Tom! I never would have thought of that.